Google Sign-In with Firebase returns 401 when accessing People API to retrieve birthdate in Flutter
I'm implementing Google Sign-In with Firebase in my Flutter app and trying to retrieve the user's birthdate using the Google People API. While the sign-in process works fine, and I get a valid accessToken, when attempting to call the People API, I encounter a 401 error saying "Request had invalid authentication credentials."
Here’s the full code I’m using:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dara_app/controller/singleton/persistent_data.dart';
import 'package:dara_app/view/shared/info_dialog.dart'; 
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; 
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/people/v1.dart';

class GoogleLogin {
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      PeopleServiceApi.userBirthdayReadScope
    ]
  );

  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

      debugPrint("checkpoint-1");
      if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
        InfoDialog().show(context: context, content: "Google sign-in was canceled", header: "Warning");
        return null;
      }

      debugPrint("checkpoint-2");
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final String? accessToken = googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken;
      debugPrint("Access-token: $accessToken");
      final String? idToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

      debugPrint("checkpoint-3");
      if (accessToken == null || idToken == null) {
        InfoDialog().show(context: context, content: "Failed to retrieve authentication tokens", header: "Warning");
        return null;
      }

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: accessToken,
        idToken: idToken,
      );

      debugPrint("checkpoint-4");
      final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      debugPrint("checkpoint-5");
      final GoogleAuthClient httpClient = GoogleAuthClient({'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'});
      PeopleServiceApi peopleApi = PeopleServiceApi(httpClient);

      debugPrint("checkpoint-6");
      final Person person = await peopleApi.people.get(
        'people/me',
        personFields: 'birthdays'
      );

      debugPrint("checkpoint-7");
      /// Birthdate
      final date = person.birthdays![0].date!;
      PersistentData().birthdayFromGoogleSignIn = date.toString();
      debugPrint("google.dart-birthday: $date");

      return userCredential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      InfoDialog().show(context: context, content: "Google sign-in error: ${e.toString()}", header: "Warning");
      debugPrint("Google sign-in error: ${e.toString()}");
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;
  final http.Client _client = http.Client();

  GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
}

The debug log shows that the process stops at checkpoint-6, and I get the following error:

Google sign-in error: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 401, message:
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2
access token, login cookie, or other valid authentication credential.

I have already ensured that:
· The accessToken is not null (I logged it to check). My Google Cloud Console shows 1 request with 0 errors, so I am unsure if that is relevant.
· I have already set the correct scopes: PeopleServiceApi.userBirthdayReadScope.
Questions:
· Am I missing any configurations in Google Cloud Console?
· Is there anything wrong with how I’m using the access token for the People API call?
